# Python save request cookies into json properly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

Hi I would like to save my python requests cookies into a text file as json like so:

```
{"Proxy": "Cookies"}
```

At the moment im using:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    proxy_data = json.load(f)

r = requests.get(URL,proxies=proxies, cookies=proxy_data['127:000'])

proxy_data['127:000'] = dict(session.cookies)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(proxy_data, json_file)
```

My data.txt file looks like this after writing it:

```
{"127:000": "{\"__cf_bm\": \"628f4c77a5139148cf28961a73f4edffed52f8c1-1622925414-1800-AaLguAyS9Hfl8TXCaQYUjjZ5i3sDck15kn/vcPJCWZBxi+nM9xU0zd/GfyKJu6/3R+GQEFdk/DGHEV4mANvpG1UMvcsXA9G9l/AFNEnIknTv\", \"cf_clearance\": \"84bffd070fbafcb91edcfa82f8cc3ba5a60a618d-1622925414-0-150\", \"cf_chl_seq_b116a013f9e2c44\": \"d3ac4406fc56d30\"}"}
```

However I run into a number of errors here. How can I do the properly?

**UPDATE**

ERRORS I GET

> Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 524, in
> cookiejar_from_dict
> cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name])) TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What errors are you facing? Can you edit your answer to include the errors?

Comment: @user5305519 i uploaded them

Comment: @PhpCoder223, can you add the code which assigns to `session` ? Is it an instance of requests.session?

Comment: @SujanAdiga yes it is

Comment: Your data.txt file has value for "127:000" escaped, that is the reason why requests.get is failing. From the code and example you have provided, it isn't clear why the value is being escaped.

Comment: @SujanAdiga that cant be right ... as im getting the cookies ... so im getting the json value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the value of `proxy_data["127:000"]` is a string which you're passing into the `cookies` parameter.

```py
with open("data.txt") as f:
    proxy_data = json.load(f)

print(type(proxy_data["127:000"]))
# >> <class 'str'>
```

Two options:

1. Parse the value of `proxy_data["127:000"]` to a dictionary using `json.loads`

`r = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies, cookies=json.loads(proxy_data['127:000']))`

2. Make sure to save the nested dicts correctly.

```py
proxy_data = {"127:000": {"cookie_test": "value_test"}}
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(proxy_data))

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    proxy_data = json.loads(f.read())

print(type(proxy_data["127:000"]))
# >> <class 'dict'>
```